# Flutter: how to link multiple photos or a photo inside an icon to a geolocation mark?

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps

I am completely at a loss. The fact is that "google_maps_flutter" only allows the BitmapDescriptor type to customize the geolocation mark. But what if I want to load a photo from the database and at the same time have some kind of contour around this photo? How in this case can I change the custom marker?

Answer (score 0):

i suppose you can do something like this :

```
  BitmapDescriptor pinLocationIcon;

      BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
         ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: 2.5),
         'assets/destination_map_marker.png').then((onValue) {
            pinLocationIcon = onValue;
         });
```

Comment: Yes, but it only allows me to add 1 photo. But I need to attach several photos, or merge them into one (I tried, but I can't), or somehow draw a contour around the photo.

Comment: i think you should check this : https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/place_marker.dart

Comment: it from the package examples it self , you can check it , it's for adding multi place markers